# Using fread on binary file into a struct in C

Tags: c

Infile is a .bin file and AI_FileHeader is a struct with 3 ints and I keep getting the error **error: expected expression before ‘AI_FileHeader’**

```
fread(AI_FileHeader, sizeof(AI_FileHeader) ,1 , infile);
```

I've tried it with &. But I get the same error.

```
fread(&AI_FileHeader, sizeof(AI_FileHeader), 1, infile);




typedef struct {
   int file_size;
   int section_table_offset; 
   int section_count;
} AI_FileHeader;
```

*Solved*

```
AI_FileHeader head;

fread(&head, sizeof(AI_FileHeader), 1,infile);
```

Comment: More context is needed. See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's the definition of `AI_FileHeader`?

Comment: typedef struct {
    int file_size;
    int section_table_offset; 
    int section_count;
} AI_FileHeader;

Comment: Fread prototype is as following size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream ); You're passing a datatype as the destination for the bytes read from the file to be stored

Comment: `AI_FileHeader` is a type and not an actual variable. So you can't use that in `fread`. Try: `AI_FileHeader header; fread(&header, sizeof(header) ,1 , infile);`

Comment: That works! Thank you